# Can a business build upon letting customers send emails via my SES account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Would it be possible to let my customers conduct email marketing transparently using my SES account. To put in other words, I will be providing them an SaaS a product, they will use it to create email campaigns (lets say, like MailChimp), and they will pay me. (Of course I will be paying for the AWS costs).

Obviously, it should be assumed that there will be troublesome customers violating spam rules from time to time. And of course, their contracts with my business will be terminated immediately when noticed. But how would this affect my SES account? Is it possible to create a model where, me as the account holder would not be punished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  But I don't know that I would recommend it.  You're limited to a maximum of 1,000 "from" email addresses and start with a max quota of 10,000 messages per day.  The number of email addresses is a hard limit, while the send quota is throttled up/down depending on how your reputation changes.  And yes, all of your customers would penalized if your customers start sending spam through your account.

I get the impression that SES was designed more for integration into a SaaS applications that aren't primarily about email.  For example, if you provided a SaaS app that allowed your customers to watch Ebay for price changes and get emailed notifications, or if you're hosting a bookkeeping app: allow your customers to email invoices to their customers.

There are a lot of other options out there though:

- [JangoSMTP](http://www.jangosmtp.com)
- [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/)
- [Sendgrid](http://www.sendgrid.com)
- Etc...

As much as I'm an AWS guy, I think there are better choices than SES for transactional email.